# How to read the names of open windows within an app and close a specific window, but not the entire application in an OSX app

Tags: swift, macos

Using a Mac menubar app that is always running I want to detect when a specific app is opened, for example Pages. Then I need to be able to read the names of all the windows that are open within the Pages app and close a specific window I am looking for.

Comment: Thanks @EricD . I understand your code, but how would I go about getting a specific window from the NSNotification in the activated function. For example, if I have two different windows open of Pages and switch to Pages the print(name) will return 'Pages". However, I am looking for a way to get the name of the specific window open within Pages, so that I can close only that window.

Comment: Well that's different from your original question: [edit] your question, change your title, *explain with details what you actually need* then I'll reopen, because then it will be different than the duplicate.

Comment: @EricD I edited the question. My needs changed after receiving your original answer

Comment: Yes. I've reopened your question now that you've edited it with your actual requirement.